# Make enter key behave like tab key in Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp-classic, visual-studio-2005, keycode

So far i have this being called on keypress.

```
function chkenter()
{
  e = event.keyCode;

  if (e == 13)
  {
    event.keyCode = 9;
    return false;
  }
}
```

but even though i set the keycode to 9 it doesn't tab over to the next control. How can i accomplish this? I'm working in Asp Classic.

What I ultimately want is for the focus to move to the next element. The next element's id, however, is not determined completely because its id was set in a loop, but at this point it exists. **How can i set focus to the next control is the question.**

Comment: You tagged this question with VS2005. That makes you sound a lot like this person with the same question: http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?t=18598

Comment: @crescent That was posted 6 years ago... also nearly 2 years before VS2005 was available...

Comment: @Rex: your point? The same question in a different version of VS *may* have the same resolution.

Comment: Crescent - that doesn't help my issue - at all. He found no real solution in that forum.

Comment: What browser are you targeting? I believe your code would work in IE but not other browsers. I'm not sure how to do this in other browsers but I've seen a very similar code snippet working in IE 5.5+.

Comment: it is in IE. but i think this has the right idea but it's too late because the key code has already been set and fired at this time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is an IE only script, so if you try to run it on firefox it wont work.

For it to work on IE, remove "return false;" from your code and dont forget to atach this function into "onkeydown" event.

Comment: That's correct. Thanks. I should have realized this. The onkeydown is right before on key press. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) like so:

```
function checkKey(e){
    if( e.keyCode == 13 ){ // if enter key
        var e = jQuery.Event('keydown'); // create a manual event
        e.which = e.charCode = 0;
        e.keyCode = 9; // set the new event to "tab"
        $(this.target).trigger(e); // trigger the new event (on the document)
        return false;  // cancels the original "enter" event from executing
    }
}
// lets say you bind the event on the whole document...
$(document).on('keydown', checkKey);
```